# Unable to parse value from HTML using jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I'm relatively new to using jsoup, and I can't seem to find the correct query to parse out the value I'm looking for. The HTML is as follows.

```
    <img src='http://rootzwiki.com/public/style_images/ginger/t_unread.png' alt='New Replies' /><br />

</a>
</td>
<td class='col_f_content '>



    <h4><a id="tid-link-12251" href="http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12251-romlte-rootzboat-403-v61/" title='View topic, started  17 December 2011 - 09:32 AM' class='topic_title'>[ROM][LTE] RootzBoat 4.0.3 V6.1</a></h4>
    <br />
    <span class='desc lighter blend_links'>
        Started by <a hovercard-ref="member" hovercard-id="5" class="_hovertrigger url fn " href='http://rootzwiki.com/user/5-birdman/'>birdman</a>, 17 Dec 2011

    </span>

        <ul class='mini_pagination'>


                    <li><a href="http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12251-romlte-rootzboat-403-v61/" title='Go to page 1'>1</a></li>




                    <li><a href="http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12251-romlte-rootzboat-403-v61/page__st__10" title='Go to page 2'>2</a></li>




                    <li><a href="http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12251-romlte-rootzboat-403-v61/page__st__20" title='Go to page 3'>3</a></li>




                    <li><a href="http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12251-romlte-rootzboat-403-v61/page__st__1990" title='Go to page 200'>200 &rarr;</a></li>


        </ul>

</td>
<td class='col_f_preview __topic_preview'>

        <a href='http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12251-romlte-rootzboat-403-v61/' class='expander closed' title='Preview this topic'>&nbsp;</a>

</td>
<td class='col_f_views desc blend_links'>
    <ul>
        <li>



                    <span class='ipsBadge ipsBadge_orange'>Hot</span>&nbsp;

                <a href="http://rootzwiki.com/index.php?app=forums&amp;module=extras&amp;section=stats&amp;do=who&amp;t=12251" onclick="return ipb.forums.retrieveWhoPosted( 12251 );">1,999 replies</a>
        </li>
        <li class='views desc'>180,213 views</li>
    </ul>
</td>
<td class='col_f_post'>
    <a href='http://rootzwiki.com/user/49940-jakeday/' class='ipsUserPhotoLink left'>
        <img src='http://rootzwiki.com/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-49940.jpg' class='ipsUserPhoto ipsUserPhoto_mini' />
    </a>
    <ul class='last_post ipsType_small'>
        <li><a hovercard-ref="member" hovercard-id="49940" class="_hovertrigger url fn " href='http://rootzwiki.com/user/49940-jakeday/'>jakeday</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href='http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12251-romlte-rootzboat-403-v61/page__view__getlastpost' title='Go to last post'>Today, 04:20 AM</a>
        </li>                               
    </ul>
</td>
```

I need to parse out `birdman` from there. I know that once I've defined the element, I can get "birdman" out with `author.text();`, but I cant figure out how to define the author element. I thought perhaps the following block of code would work, but as I mentioned, I'm pretty new to jsoup and html and it obviously didnt work. Theres nothing wrong with the connection, and jsoup is working for the other values I parsed out.

```
            TitleResults titleArray =  new TitleResults();
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(Constants.FORUM).get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Elements threads = doc.select(".topic_title");
                for (Element thread : threads) {
                    titleArray =  new TitleResults();
                    //Thread title
                    threadTitle = thread.text();
                    titleArray.setItemName(threadTitle);

                    //Thread link
                    String threadStr = thread.attr("abs:href");
                    String endTag = "/page__view__getnewpost"; //trim link
                    threadStr = new String(threadStr.replace(endTag, ""));
                    threadArray.add(threadStr);

                    titleArray.setAuthorDate("Author/Date");
                    results.add(titleArray);
                }
                Elements authors = doc.select("a[hovercard-ref]");
                for (Element author : authors) {
                    if (author.attr("abs:href").contains("/user/")){
                        Log.d("POC", "SUCCESS " + author.attr("abs:href"));
                    } else {
                        Log.d("POC", "FAILURE " + author.text());                           
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: `doc.select("a[hovercard-ref]");` works like a charm ... just think few hints: mobile version, user agent, html dump on device ...

Comment: that didnt work for me. it was one of the first things i tried?

Comment: how you getting html ? (not exacly but URLConnection/apache/other ?) http://pastebin.com/xfUQkGw0 `12-13 21:06:44.462: D/POC(4391): SyNiK4L http://rootzwiki.com/user/242-synik4l/
12-13 21:06:44.462: D/POC(4391): SyNiK4L http://rootzwiki.com/user/242-synik4l/
12-13 21:06:44.462: D/POC(4391): Rythmyc http://rootzwiki.com/user/6325-rythmyc/
12-13 21:06:44.462: D/POC(4391): Rythmyc http://rootzwiki.com/user/6325-rythmyc/`

Comment: wtf :(. Lol i dont understand why its not working for me. i updated the example code to show the entire method. The html is held at Constant.FORUM in the form of a string. Works fine for the title and url of the threads.

Comment: Well, I dont understand how your method was different, but it works, thank you. Thank you. If youd like to copy that pastebin into an answer, i can accept it as the answer and close this.

Comment: nvm ... remeber to use AsyncTask/Services for loading/downloading stuff from web ... (do not use ProgressDialog ... it sucks ... just use some ProgressBar only) ... i'll go even for ContentProvider and doing data caching in SQLite db ... but it's me  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're thinking too hard ;)

To get the `birdman` portion of the link, just use the following:

```
Elements authors = doc.select("a");
for (Element author : authors) {
    Log.d("POC", author.text());
}
```

The `"a"` retrieves all links. After that you can just use the `.text()` like you said to retrieve the value.

Comment: i actually just tried that. "a" isnt returning the member links, only the thread links. this is the URL im working with. http://rootzwiki.com/forum/362-cdma-galaxy-nexus-developer-forum/

your answer returns only the thread titles. 

`[ROM] Redemption Rom ICS v1.0.1 *UPDATE* Jan 3rd 8:30pm EST`

Comment: Ah sorry didn't know there were also other types of links on the site. 
Still odd it doesn't return the member links since it worked for me with different types of links.  Did you try just using `[hovercard-ref]`?

Comment: ya I tried that too. :/ I also just updated my question with the full block of relevant code in case you see something that I overlooked

Comment: Hmm. Just throwing things out here now but try `"._hovertrigger"`, since Jsoup also works with classes that might do the trick.

Comment: Hmm. Very very odd. You DID give the app Internet permission right? ;)

Comment: of course. in the same method, i have it parsing the thread links without an issue.

Comment: could the author info perhaps be considered an attribute of the topic_title? maybe thats why the links for it arent being picked up either?

Answer (score 0):

Selvin answered it in the comments. I wasnt getting the source correctly and it was causing errors. 
http://pastebin.com/xfUQkGw0